# How to move the gradient-foreground-color text to the center of the view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, layout, swiftui, gradient

I used `Gradient` with a `.mask(_:)` modifier to implement `Text` with a gradient foreground color in SwiftUI. But the text is always at the top-leading of the view. How can I put it at the center of the view?

This is my implementation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GradientText: View {
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red, .orange]), 
                       startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            .mask(Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded)))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

And how does it look like:

[image]

Comment: It is at the center by default... did you embed it in some other view, if yes, probably the issue is there. Would you show more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `LinearGradient` is filling all of the space it is given.  If you remove the `mask`, you will see how big it is.  You'd like it to be just the size of the text.

I'm sure there's a better way to handle this, but this is what I came up with.  By starting with the text, we are able to use the `LinearGradient` as an `overlay` which will exactly match the size of the text.

```
struct GradientText: View {
    let text = Text("Hello World")
        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
    
    var body: some View {
        text
        .foregroundColor(.clear)
        .overlay(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red, .orange]),
                startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            .mask(text))
    }
}
```

---

Extending this idea further, you could make `GradientText` take `text` and `gradient` as inputs so that you could easily do this repeatedly:

```
struct GradientText: View {
    let text: Text
    let gradient: LinearGradient
    
    init(text: Text, gradient: LinearGradient? = nil) {
        self.text = text
        self.gradient = gradient ?? LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red, .orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        text
        .foregroundColor(.clear)
        .overlay(
            gradient
            .mask(text))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GradientText(text: Text("Hello World")
                .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded)))
            GradientText(text: Text("Goodnight World"), gradient: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .yellow, .orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
        }
    }
}
```